# what do you call a person who wants others to be the way they think?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call that person who wants others to behave like them?

Comment: Narrow-minded, inadequate and insecure spring to mind, but I'm not sure that's the kind of thing you want

Comment: An average human. :^)  Though if you're looking for someone who wants others to act in a uniform way (not necessarily like them, but like everyone in a group), they'd be a "conformist".  Not quite what you're looking for though, so not worth giving as an answer sadly. :( If I think of anything that better suits your needs, I'll be returning here to post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd call someone like that a ***moraliser***...

> [moralise/moralize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moralise) *- to reflect on or express opinions about something in terms of right and wrong, especially in a self-righteous or tiresome way.*

...or perhaps a ***prescriptivist***...

> [prescriptive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prescriptive) *- making or giving injunctions, directions, laws, or rules.*

Most other words in this general area (*conformist, traditionalist, conservative,* etc.) are usually used to mean a person who *wants to be like others*, rather than wants others to be like him.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for ***missionary*** and ***proselytizer***

> [***missionary***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/missionary?s=t)
>   a person strongly in favor of a program, set of principles, etc., who attempts to persuade or convert others.
>
> [***proselytizer***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/proselytizer?s=t)
>
> to convert or attempt to convert as a proselyte; recruit.

Another word is ***control freak*** (although this can be applied in a different context as well, and is rather informal)

> a person having a strong need for control over people or situations.

Answer (score 1):

How about **indoctinator**?

An indoctrinator is one who **indoctinates**.

From Dictionary.com:

> **indoctrinate**: to instruct in a doctrine, principle, ideology, etc., especially to imbue with a specific partisan or biased belief or
>   point of view.

**Indoctrinators** want others to believe and do as they do (beliefs being habits of action).

Comment: Please do not give the same answer to more than one question.